# Get Last week date ranges in php , week Monday to sunday

Tags: php

Using a Php date functions i would like to get the last week date ranges,

for example.

its Friday, 24th June 2016 Today.

I want the out put

Last week Start Date : 2016-06-13 (YYYY-mm-dd Format)

Last week End Date   : 2016-06-19 (YYYY-mm-dd Format)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php
 echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last week monday"));
 echo "<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday"));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified to use `"this week monday"` and `"this week sunday"` and seems right!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('sunday',strtotime('last week'))); //2016-06-19
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday',strtotime('last week'))); //2016-06-13
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$start_week = strtotime("last monday midnight");
$end_week = strtotime("+1 week",$start_week);

$start_week = date("Y/m/d",$start_week);
$end_week = date("Y/m/d",$end_week);

echo $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
```

Comment: it shows : 2016-06-12  - 2016-06-18

Week should start from Monday and ends on Sunday, Thats the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)
[Date formats](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.relative.php)

`strtotime('sunday', 'Fri June 24th, 2016"')`
`strtotime('monday', 'Fri June 24th, 2016"')`